# Converting DAC voltage to eurorack voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've connected a DAC to a Raspberry Pi. The DAC gives a voltage between 0V and 3.3V.

I would like to convert this to an eurorack voltage between -5V and +5V.

Using the op amp calculator at [masteringelectronicsdesign.com](https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/differential-amplifier-calculator-2/) and [circuitjs](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html) I found that this should work:

[image: schematic]

As an editable schematic: [(circuitjs)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAOAnLAzKgbBsqB2AJiMgwwBYQsQkKNaBTAWjDACgBDEIhbHyMmrIqpIalohmSMPHjhoCNNkIZkJCmE0EZitATYUCkMBmzHi4OZHYAnHnx6W1oy5Gpz2Adwf8NvpyIob2FRQVDA4PtefnwgrSo4qGoMODsAsCIhF3As5Nl4dgBzCMzskXBsd2qQmNyhOqSbACVwCkTUIOR3BPyQCh7obF1h5JgEdN7-XtSqd1JCkpnIRPaU-hr7KaIqCgad5IW01r2eA9Y-A%20r%209wxoBmvxkO3RR38bAA8pMAIUCRJfp1%20pUQAAVAAWAEsAM4AHWhACIAIIAYQRzGhAHsAK62ADGjHhAAdbJiACbYglw6GceHQyEAOxY7C%20rF%20sli3SsEkS-C8nAAboToQAjRgAFy8jEYDPhkAAavDOAyyfC7hh5dAWTcgqQIAhUPMVsCwPwceKidjxXTwTiADaq0XC6Sa6DQWFEhDy9iY6ggbBzG6oCSyKCwOBYSDYXiHP0YdhAA)

In reality though, this doesn't work. I put it on a breadboard and measured with an oscilloscope and the output is between -2.5V and +2.5V. Note that I power the op amp with -5V and +5V. The op amp is an MCP6001.

What is wrong with this schematic? Am I right that I can't rely on circuitjs and masteringelectronicsdesign.com for this, or is my breadboard setup more likely to be incorrect?

*** UPDATE ***

Conclusion:

1. I misunderstood op amps: they have a maximum difference between their Vss and Vcc (NOT neccessarily between 0V and Vcc) which can be fairly low like 6V
2. I misunderstood my function generator: 1.65Vpp means from -0.825 to +0.825 (NOT -1.65...+1.65V)
3. After replacing the op amp by a TL072, I indeed get a wave between -5V and +5V (almost, slightly less - suggestions for a better DIP op amp are welcome!)
4. I should use the -12/+12V from the eurorack power supply to feed the op amp

Comment: How are you powering your opamp?

Comment: Circuit seems correct. The op-amp you're using has a rail-to-rail input and output, so +/-5V supply should be fine.

Comment: @WesleyLee I power the op amp with -5V and +5V

Comment: Wait, hang on, that [op-amp](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf) uses a unipolar supply with max 6V rating. If you are feeding it with a -5V power rail connected to the \$V_{ss}\$ pin, with +5V connected to \$V_{dd}\$, then you are also exceeding its supply capabilities of max 6V \$V_{dd}-V_{ss}\$.

Comment: @TomCarpenter ah I did not know that. Somehow I was thinking that was relative to 0V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Date sheet page 1](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MSLD/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf): -

[image]

Also note that to truly get +/- 5 volts from a rail-to-rail op-amp that can legally be powered with +/- 5 volts, you will fall short by a few tens of mV. So, choose an op-amp supply that is slightly higher than +/- 5 volts and choose an op-amp that is R2R and won't be damaged by this voltage.

Other than that, I believe the calculator you used to be correct. Modified version for output between -4.95 volts and +4.95 volts when you only have a +/- 5 volt supply: -

[image]

Also note that the input offset voltage specified in the data sheet is +/- 4.95 mV and this will add an error to your output signal of up to +/- 15 mV. I mention this because if you change the op-amp to one that can operate on +/- 5 volts, you should take into account the errors that may be produced. Given that a Δ Vin of 3.3 volts produces a Δ Vout of 10 volts, there is an inherent circuit gain of 3 and this magnifies input offset voltages also.